# Neoclipse fails to load db

Tags: neo4j, neoclipse

[image]

I got Neoclipse, and I tried to import a neo4j db into it which was generated by this basic Neo4j hellow world program https://github.com/neo4j/neo4j/blob/2.0.0-M04/community/embedded-examples/src/main/java/org/neo4j/examples/EmbeddedNeo4j.java.
I am getting an error. I am attaching the error dialog box (as I was not able to copy the error text from the dialog for some strange reasons!)

But when I try to create a db through neo4j webadmin console, I was able to visualize that graph db in neoclipse.

Am I missing something here ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like Neoclipse may only support 1.9 databases, which are different on disk to 2.0 databases.

Comment: I dont think thats the case ... further investigation revealed that it might not be a neoclipse issue. It throws the same error if I point neo4j-server data dir to this test db i created. If interested check my question here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/neo4j/PiPm8PTSVKo

Comment: If you notice the UpgradeNotAllowedByConfigurationException, that means you are trying to run a 1.9 database in a 2.0 neo4j, or 1.8 in 1.9 (typically). Can you update your question to show the versions of things you're using. Which neo4j is in your classpath/pom for your hello world program?

Comment: You are right I got it resolved by using 1.9.x libs. Neoclipse do not support 2.0 stores (as pointed out on the neo4j google forum too)

Comment: We will look into upgrading to 2.0 soon (TM) :)